# Regular expression with delimiters

Tags: .net, regex

I would like to parse some strings using a regular expression in .NET, with a format where delimiters are `'` values and separators are `&` values:

```
'A$04'&'A&&&'&'585262&YY'&'05555'
```

The problem I find is that the separator `&` can also appear inside every single value.

Could you please point me how to do it without using a loop? I tried some regular expressions but did not succeed.

Comment: Post your regex that you have tried so far...

Comment: If you don't need to check the data structure, you can only extract what is between quotes.

Comment: You can explode/split the string for `'&'`

Comment: Why do yo have to use regex?  .NET has a parser.  TextFieldParser http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'[^']+'(&'[^']+')*
```

This should work unless you can have apostrophes inside your fields. Note that I assume your fields cannot be empty - Replace `+` with `*` to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] splitArray = null;
try {
    splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, "'(.*?)'");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}


Match the character “'” literally «'»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the character “'” literally «'»
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to split:

```
string[] values = Regex.Split("'A$04'&'A&&&'&'585262&YY'&'05555'", "(?<=')&(?=')");
```

We split by `&` preceded by `'` and followed by `'`.

```
(?<=')&(?=')
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6aggVlUxFvZNXMHH)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
        var r = new Regex("'[A-Z0-9&$]*'",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        var matches = r.Matches("'A$04'&'A&&&'&'585262&YY'&'05555'");
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            var finalValue = match.ToString().Replace("'","");
        }
```